# How to store IP Address in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to `scp` a file from a remote machine to my machine using a shell script:

```
SRC_PASS="pass" 
SRC_PORT="22" 
SRC_USER="root" 
SRC_IP="x.x.x.x"
TAR_SRC="/tmp/abc.gz" 

echo $SRC_IP 
sshpass -p $SRC_PASS scp -P $SRC_PORT $SRC_USER@$SRC_IP:$TAR_SRC /tmp/xy.gz
```

I have debugged and found out that the `$SRC_IP` for some reason isn't storing the IP address properly.

For example, it works if I use this:

```
sshpass -p $SRC_PASS scp -P $SRC_PORT $SRC_USER@x.x.x.x:$TAR_SRC /tmp/xy.gz
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo` instead of `print`?

Comment: Now that it's `echo`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: My bad @JNevill Rectified that in the question

Comment: And what is the output of `echo $SRC_IP` ? Add `set -x` at beginning and show the trace ...

Comment: `++ SRC_PASS=pass
++ SRC_PORT=22
++ SRC_USER=root
++ SRC_IP=x.x.x.x
++ TAR_SRC=/tmp/abc.gz
++ echo x.x.x.x
10.106.124.136
++ sshpass -p pass scp -P 22 root@x.x.x.x:/tmp/abc.gz /tmp/xy.gz`
@PeterMmm

Comment: Works for me, you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I tried that. It assumes the variable to be something else altogether and says password is wrong. If I replace the variable with the actual IP address, it works perfectly. Same in case of with or without sshpass

Comment: Always, _always_ quote usage of variables: `sshpass -p "$SRC_PASS" scp -P "$SRC_PORT" "$SRC_USER"@"$SRC_IP":"$TAR_SRC" /tmp/xy.gz`

Comment: Or `"$SRC_USER@$SRC_IP:$TAR_SRC"` -- they don't need to be *individually* quoted. (Also shouldn't be all-caps -- see relevant POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html indicating that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the system and shell, whereas others are reserved to be safe for application use).

Comment: @vedang09, if you can provide code someone else can run to see code *not* working themselves -- a [mcve] -- that would do a great deal of good. For that matter, providing -- and comparing -- the `set -x` logs with both the `$SRC_IP` expansion and the hardcoded address would do a great deal of good. If the shell truly *is* doing something wrong, those two log lines will differ.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need to enclose your variable names in curly braces so the shell does not consider "@" or ":" as part of the variable name. Example:

```
sshpass -p $SRC_PASS scp -P $SRC_PORT ${SRC_USER}@${SRC_IP}:${TAR_SRC} /tmp/xy.gz
```

If that's not the issue and the script is in bash, use

```
bash -x /path/to/script.txt
```

To execute it and see the issue.

Comment: Neither `@` or `:` is valid in a variable name, so curly braces are not needed in either case. You can test this yourself: `var1=hello; var2=world; echo "$var1:$var2@"` properly emits `hello:world@`